# Translucent Status Bar Bug

Tags: android, statusbar, android-4.4-kitkat, scringo

I have a problem with the translucent `statusbar` only when opening of the app for the first time. 
Take a look at the screenshot:
[image]
When opening the `Navigation Drawer` this bug appears, but only on first opening of the app. When I close my app and start it again, everything works fine.

Here is the XML of the Style I use which is including the translucent Status Bar:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="TransTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.GreenStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.GreenStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item> 
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Were you planning on posting any code or hoping that we can divine a solution from that picture?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I guess a bit of code would be nice, will add it to the first post.

Comment: Has somebody an idea? Ive been trying to fix that problem for hours now...

Comment: @Line.Dev did you ever find a fix for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` as attribute to the `ListView` of the drawer directly.

Comment: The drawer is provided by an Library (www.scringo.com) so I dont know where to look for the exact ListView...

Comment: You could try contacting the scringo team directly: support@scringo.com